# React native react-navigation tabBarIcon does not display

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm having a TabNavigator where I want to have icons at each tab together with a label. However, even though I've tried numerous ways in order to get the icon to appear, nothing happens.

```
// Imports...

const StartScreen =  TabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: HomeTab,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Test',
            tabBarIcon:() => <Icon size={ 20 } name={ 'cogs' } color={ 'red' }/>
        }
    },
    Calendar: {
        screen: CalendarTab,
        navigationOptions: {}
    }
});

StartScreen.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'TestApp',
    headerTintColor: '#ffa500',
    showIcon: true
};

export default StartScreen;
```

And yes, I've tried out using the Icon-component so I know that it works.

Any tips or guidance would be really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This works

```
const StartScreen =  TabNavigator({
  Home: {
    ...
  },
  Calendar: {
    ...
  },
},  {  
  tabBarOptions: { 
    showIcon: true 
  }, 
});
```

**EDIT**: I just checked and there is no google material icon named cogs. You should double check your naming :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with version 1.0.0-beta14.

For me, upgrading to 1.0.0-beta15 fixed it

Answer (score 0):

try to use `tabBarOptions = {{ showIcon: true }}`

I had the same problem , I have to force the display of my icons I set `showIcon` to true. This previously solved my problem.

Comment: You should explain why you think your answer is correct.

Comment: I had the same problem , I have to force the display of my icons I set showIcon to true

Comment: Added the explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

what is the version your react-navigation is???

you can try this

```
navigationOptions: {
            tabBar: {
                label: 'Test',
                icon: ({tintColor}) => (<Icon ... />),
            },
        }
```

it will work in version `1.0.0-beta.7`

Comment: I always strive to have the newest packages so now its 1.0.0-beta.11 and that syntax was removed in beta-8 as I remember. Worst case scenario is that I will go back a few versions

Answer (score -2):

Try adding **return** before the icon, like this:

```
tabBarIcon:() => return <Icon size={ 20 } name={ 'cogs' } color={ 'red' }/>
```