# Why does tabBarIcon not navigate to my component in my Tab.Screen?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

When building a custom `Tab.Screen` I've tried to pass a custom `tabBarIcon`. While the icon renders it will not navigate to the component `TestScreen`. In the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#options) for [`tabBarIcon`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaricon) my understanding the `Tab.Screen` should be written as:

```jsx
<Tab.Screen
  name={routes.FOO}
  component={TestScreen}
  options={{
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.actionButton}>
          <Image source={plus} style={styles.imageIcon} />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

When I omit the `options`:

```jsx
<Tab.Screen
  name={routes.FOO}
  component={TestScreen}
/>
```

the `onClick` renders the component when clicked. When I read the docs for [Options for screens](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options/) it mentions `screenOptions` should be passed on the Navigator or Group. I tried to see if I could find a similar Q&A:

- [React native react-navigation tabBarIcon does not display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603911/react-native-react-navigation-tabbaricon-does-not-display)
- [Why Is My Component not Rendering Within my Tab.Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091562/why-is-my-component-not-rendering-within-my-tab-screen)

but I was unable to see where my error is.

My current dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
  "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
  "expo": "~42.0.1",
  "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
  "react": "16.13.1",
  "react-dom": "16.13.1",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
  "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
  "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0",
  "react-native-screens": "~3.4.0",
  "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.9.0"
},
```

How can I get my custom icon to render and navigate to the correct component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaving this as an answer hoping it helps someone else down the road. After sleeping on this I examined my `Tab.Screen` again and I remembered for a `TouchableOpacity` to work it needed an `onPress` even though I was thinking the parent would take care of the navigation but this wasn't the case.

While this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69716732/1952287) is somewhat accurate, with removing the `TouchableOpacity`, it would make the icon work, code:

```js
<Tab.Screen
  name={routes.FOO}
  component={TestScreen}
  options={{
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <View style={styles.actionButton}>
        <Image source={plus} style={styles.imageIcon} />
      </View>
    ),
  }}
/>
```

but it defeats the purpose of a custom button and the opacity change. After looking closer at `options` I wondered what if I passed down the `navigation` to `onPress` and used `navigate`?

Well it worked and I was left with:

```js
<Tab.Screen
  name={routes.FOO}
  component={TestScreen}
  options={({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: () => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.FOO)}>
        <View style={styles.actionButton}>
          <Image source={plus} style={styles.imageIcon} />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    ),
  })}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TouchableOpacity` is overlap with react navigation internal press handler,  just wrap your icon with `View`

If you want customize press behavior of tab icon pass the listener object to `listener` props https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/#listeners-prop-on-screen